# How do i sort structure array with pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, structure

Write a program to enter id, name, and address to a structure array and sort them in ascending order on the basis of the name with the use of pointer?

I tried searching for so many questions in this forum, but none of them exactly helped me out. So this is my code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
struct student
{
    char name[20], add[30];
    int id;
};
int main()
{
    struct student s[100];
    struct student *sptr;
    int i, j, temp, n;
    char tempc[30];
    sptr=&s;
    printf("How many students do we have to register?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the id, name and address of the students and hit enter.");

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%s%s",&sptr->id,&sptr->name,&sptr->add);
        sptr++;
    }
    sptr=&s;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(s[i].name,s[j].name)>0)
            {
                strcpy(tempc,(sptr+i)->name);
                strcpy(sptr->name,(sptr+j)->name);
                strcpy((sptr+j)->name,tempc);
                strcpy(tempc,sptr->add);
                strcpy(sptr->add,(sptr+j)->add);
                strcpy((sptr+j)->add,tempc);
                temp=(sptr+j)->id;
                sptr->id=(sptr+j)->id;
                (sptr+j)->id=temp;

            }
        }
    }
    printf("The sorted form is:");

     for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d%s%s",sptr->id,sptr->name,sptr->add);
        sptr++;
    }



}
```

If you're getting where I'm going, please help me out. And yeah I don't want to use any memory allocation functions or sizeof() function.

Comment: Fyi, C supports structure assignment. Your structure is fully enclosed (there are no pointers leading to other data). Therefore, all of those member copies are pointless. , you can just declare a temp `struct student` and do regular element swaps on your array. You also need to turn up your compiler warnings, as it should tell you there are numerous places where `char *` is what is called for, but `char (*)[20]` is what is being provided (they're not synonymous types).  Same goes for `sptr = &s;` where `sptr = s;` is what should be there.

Comment: BTW `sizeof` is not a function, but an operator, probably it's only operand being constanlty surrounded with parenthesis, _only needed when applied to a type_, makes it a little bit confussing, however. this is perfectly legal: `size_t myobject_size = sizeof arrayelem[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) like following:

```
int compare_student (const void * a, const void * b)
{

  struct student *lhs = (struct student *)a;
  struct student *rhs = (struct student *)b;

  return strcmp( lhs->name, rhs->name) ;
}

// N = total number of students;

qsort (s, N, sizeof(struct student), compare_student);
```

Comment: Hey! i simplified my code to this: https://pastebin.com/m0dF3WRu And it is still not sorting them, Can you please correct me?